# Integer seconds to formated string mm:ss

Tags: java, strings, android, datetime, converting

I have a `String` like "Time left (XX)" or "You need stay here for (XX)" and `int` as second. I use those two variables to format label like "string (mm:ss)" example "Time left (59:23)".

```
private String timeDescription(String pDescription,int pTime) {

    final String preformatedTime = secondsToString(pTime);
    final String timeForReturn = putTimeInXX(pDescription,preformatedTime);
    return timeForReturn;
}

private String secondsToString(int pTime) {
    final int min = pTime/60;
    final int sec = pTime-(min*60);

    final String strMin = placeZeroIfNeede(min);
    final String strSec = placeZeroIfNeede(sec);
    return String.format("%s:%s",strMin,strSec);
}

private String placeZeroIfNeede(int number) {
    return (number >=10)? Integer.toString(number):String.format("0%s",Integer.toString(number));
}

private String putTimeInXX(String pDescription,String pTime) {
    String[] apartDescription = pDescription.split("XX");

    StringBuilder descriptionForReturn = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < apartDescription.length; i++) {
        descriptionForReturn.append(apartDescription[i]);
        if (i == 0) {
            descriptionForReturn.append(pTime);
        }
    }
    return descriptionForReturn.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hello! You have received four answers. Would you please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of them? This gives you and the person with the accepted answer more reputation and gets this question off the list of unanswered questions. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code looks functional, and, if this was for early versions of Java, it would be quite typical and standard.

The `String.format` process can do so much more than what you are using it for, though.

Your function:

> ```
> private String secondsToString(int pTime) {
>     final int min = pTime/60;
>     final int sec = pTime-(min*60);
>
>     final String strMin = placeZeroIfNeede(min);
>     final String strSec = placeZeroIfNeede(sec);
>     return String.format("%s:%s",strMin,strSec);
> }
> ```

can be simplified drastically by using more of the `String.format` functionality:

```
private String secondsToString(int pTime) {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", pTime / 60, pTime % 60);
}
```

The `%02d` means: *"Format as a decimal number using at least 2 digits, and pad with 0 if less than 2 digits"*

Note, that using the modulo 60 `pTime % 60` gets the remainder of seconds when dividing by 60. This is  short hand for `pTime - (ptime / 60) * 60`

Comment: If you incorporate the format string too - so `Time Left: %02d:%02d` them you would also get rid of the OP's strange loop.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - you are right. I considered making that change/addition immediately after I posted this answer, but then I thought it would compete too much with ZeroOne's answer too. Feel free to upvote his answer. It recommends exactly what you are suggesting.

Comment: The code wouldn't work in early versions of Java, since it calls `String.format()`.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of a custom "placeZeroIfNeeded" method you could just use the ready-made [number formatting possibilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) of Java:

```
final String strMin = String.format("%02d", min);
final String strSec = String.format("%02d", sec);
```

Then, you don't really need your `putTimeInXX` method either, you can do it like this:

```
final String timeForReturn = pDescription.replace("XX", preformattedTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't require to loop it through to make a string; you could use a replace method in Java and just replace with your time string.

> ```
> final int sec = pTime-(min*60);
> ```

This is not required; you could take modulo of input number.

```
private String timeDescription(String pDescription,int pTime) {
    return putTimeInXX(pDescription,secondsToString(pTime));
}

private String secondsToString(int pTime) {
    final int min = pTime / 60;
    final int sec = pTime % 60;

    final String strMin = placeZeroIfNeeded(min);
    final String strSec = placeZeroIfNeeded(sec);
    return String.format("%s:%s",strMin,strSec);
}

private String placeZeroIfNeeded(int number) {
    return (number >=10)? Integer.toString(number):String.format("0%s",Integer.toString(number));
}

private String putTimeInXX(String inputDescription,String pTime) {
    return inputDescription.replace("XX",pTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That entire code could be reduced to these few lines:

```
private String timeDescription(String description, int seconds) {
    return putTimeInXX(description, secondsToString(seconds));
}

private String secondsToString(int seconds) {
    return String.format("%02d:%02d", seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
}

private String putTimeInXX(String description, String timeString) {
    return description.replaceAll("XX", timeString);
}
```

[@rolfl](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31503/rolfl) already pointed out about `secondsToString`.

The `int pTime` parameter was not well-named: the Hungarian notation is not recommended, simple English words are better. In this case, the method formats seconds to string, so `seconds` would be a much more natural name. I changed all the variable names following this logic.

The `putTimeInXX` method was too tedious: splitting the input string on `XX` just to replace it? It's a lot easier and natural to use `String.replace` or `String.replaceAll`. Also, I would recommend using `%s` in the input string, that way you could replace the `%s` template even more efficiently using `String.format`:

```
private String putTimeInXX(String description, String timeString) {
    return String.format(description, timeString);
}
```

In the `timeDescription` method, the intermediary `final` variables were really pointless. You can simply insert the method calls in a single expression, and the line is still not too long, and you have a much shorter method.